# psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server when called from Google Cloud Run

Tags: ssl, psycopg2, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, unix-socket

I have a (Linux) Docker image that connects successfully to Google's Cloud SQL when I run it as a container on my local machine.  When I move that image to Google's container registry and put it in a Google Cloud Run API, I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out Is the server running on host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
    at connect (/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:130)
    ...
```

I'm assuming that this is because I have the Cloud SQL instance configured to be a "Public IP" with a list of "Authorized Networks".  See documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-ip?_ga=2.129595788.-1431414204.1612902707)

The problem is that based on how/when I deploy the Cloud Run API, the IP address could change over time.  How do I authorize access to the Cloud SQL instance from other Google Cloud services (specifically Google Cloud Run) that belong to my project (not other projects)?

### Update

Based on the comment from John Hanley (see this [URL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#command-line)), I was able to update my deploy command by adding the following to my `gcloud beta run deploy` command:

```
--add-cloudsql-instances=[CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME] --service-account=service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

The SQL connection still isn't working though.  I think I've done everything on this webpage I can think of except for re-writing my SQL connection python code.  Is writing your connection in unix-socket format as shown on this page required?

I have code already written that uses SSL client certificates.  Here's 2 methods from the class that I use for my connections:

```py
def get_db_connection(self):
    file_map = {os.path.abspath(f'{TEMP_PATH}/sslrootcert.pem'): self.sslrootcert,
                os.path.abspath(f'{TEMP_PATH}/sslcert.pem'): self.sslcert,
                os.path.abspath(f'{TEMP_PATH}/sslkey.pem'): self.sslkey}
    rev_map = {v: k for k, v in file_map.items()}
    db = None
    try:
        for path, obj in file_map.items():
            with open(path, 'w') as f:
                if isinstance(obj, bytes):
                    f.write(obj.decode('utf-8'))
                else:
                    f.write(str(obj))
            os.chmod(path, stat.S_IRWXU)

        db = psycopg2.connect(database=self.database, user=self.user, password=self.password, host=self.host,
                              port=self.port, sslmode=self.sslmode, sslrootcert=rev_map.get(self.sslrootcert),
                              sslcert=rev_map.get(self.sslcert), sslkey=rev_map.get(self.sslkey))
    finally:
        for path in file_map.keys():
            if os.path.isfile(path):
                os.remove(path)
    return db

@contextlib.contextmanager
def db_connect(self):
    db = self.get_db_connection()
    cur = db.cursor()
    try:
        yield (db, cur)
    finally:
        db.close()
```

### Update 2

I'm still workinng on trying all of the things suggested, but I realized that my Cloud SQL database is setup to "Allow only SSL connections":
[image]

Could this be the reason why the connection is failing when running in Cloud Run, but succeeding on my local machine (in or out of a Docker container)?  If so, how should the Cloud Run settings be changed to account for this?

### Final Update

Using a Unix Socket based connection (from [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#python)) allowed the connection to start working.  Why does a connection from Google Cloud Run to Google Cloud SQL require a Unix Socket connection?  Is there a way to get it to work with the SSL certificate method/code I have above?

Comment: Google Cloud Run provides Cloud SQL Auth Proxy support. This is covered in the documentation with examples. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run

Comment: John Hanley, Thanks for pointing me to this document.  I didn't find this when googling for this issue.  It helped me fix 2 issues that I'm updating in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

I used this [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#command-line) which is also suggested by John Hanley which mentions a step by step process to connect Cloud run with SQL using unix sockets. I also referred to this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvZXbJv6qJ4) when I was stuck, although the video is using php, I think it might still be useful for you. I used the code provided in the documentation for the connection, that is connecting with unix sockets, and I was able to deploy it successfully.

I used the below command to deploy:

`gcloud run deploy --image [image-name] --platform managed --add-cloudsql-instances [CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME] --set-env-vars CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME=[CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME]`

I also recommend verifying your entrypoint, check if it is the correct image that you want to deploy.

Verify if Cloud Run has associated permissions as defined in [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#command-line).

Also, Google's recommendation is to use [private IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/private-ip#overview) instead of public IP, as you are connecting the GCP products internally there will be lower latency compared to public IP.